# How to set persistence-enabled to false in Corda for Artemis AMQP config

Tags: corda, activemq-artemis

How to set persistence-enabled=false in Corda 4.x Artermis ActiveMQ?
We would like to prevent writing sensitive/PII data into disk/journal.